# Porqué el primer argumento devuelve undefined - JS

Tags: javascript

Tengo la siguiente función, busco que la función acepte todos los parámetros que le quiera pasar y me devuelva un string único en la variable resultado:

```
function concatenar(){
    var resultado;
    var args = [...arguments];
    for(let i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
        resultado += args[i];
    };
    return resultado;
}
```

Por algún motivo, cuando paso parámetros, el primero me devuelve undefined.
Cuál puede ser el motivo?
Gracias

Comment: porque resultado es `undefined`, si la declaras antes con `var resultado = "";` dejará de estar `undefined`

Comment: Muchas gracias Nicolas! Resuelto

Answer (score 0):

No has definido la variable resultado, olvidaste darle un valor

```
var resultado = '';
```